# Active Storage - Specify disk for specific model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Im using active record in my rails 5.2 app.

I have the disk set as `:amazon` in my production config, however there are some models that have attached file that I would like to store in `:local`.

Is there a way I can specify perhaps at the `:has_attached :file` on the model, that I want it to store it in `:local` and not `:amazon`?

Comment: You can explore the [mirror service](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#mirror-service) and write your own wrapper around to achieve that as there is no direct approach it seems..